# Tips on increasing light

Tags: rendering, light, lighting

I have been following a tutorial by BlenderGuru. I've done a render below however the scene seems to be quite dark, even though there are several light sources involved. Sorry if this is a noob question but any tips on increasing the light levels? Let me know if you need to see any particular settings as I'm still new to this...

[image]

Comment: Just increase the value for the emitter.

Comment: Increase the value for the emitter as segaton said, bute note that will still be noise heavy since your light source are small. You can also add general light intensity with ambient occlusion.

Comment: You could also try using Filmic Blender. BlenderGuru also made a video on this but  you shouldn't need to install Filmic separately. Blender 2.79 added built in filmic color management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Cycles render, select the light source and just go to the light tab in the inspector. There, just bump up the strength! Alternately, you could add more light sources, or change the lighting type.